# Lectures of many valued logic

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, logic

I am looking for a good introduction to this topic... something with lots of examples and models would be nice.

I am specially interested by the case where the truth values are open sets in a topological set, and in general by applications to intuitionistic logic; and, maybe, to topos theory...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Priest, An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic: From If to Is

Comment: "... where the truth values are open sets ..." suggests modal logics such as S4 and S5, where the modal operators satisfy the Kuratowski axioms. This is mentioned briefly in various texts but I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly, and don't know of any with "lots of examples and models."